# df.iloc function in pandas not workiing

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to locate all rows that have N/A for a particular column, however my code isn't working...

```py
df_train.iloc[lambda x: x.value.isna()]
```

Comment: `.iloc` doesn't take a boolean as an argument, it does take a function but one that returns a valid input for indexing. use `.loc`. Additionally, what's wrong with `df.isna()` ?

Comment: Filtering with a callable is indeed useful if you are doing method chaining. simply change `iloc` to `loc`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
df_train.loc[df_train.value.isna()]
```

If you really want to do it with `iloc` try next one:

```
df_train.iloc[lambda x: x[x.value.isna()].index]
```

This is needed because `iloc` is a purely index-based selection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
df_train[df_train["particularColumnName"].isna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! `loc` does take callable with a boolean return, so you can do

```
df_train.loc[lambda x: x.value.isna()]
```